# Does the lack of absurdities in our universe call into question the validity of multi verse theories?

Tags: multiverse

Does the lack of absurdities in our universe call into question the validity of multi verse theories?

If the theories about multi verse are to be true and we have explained the immensely improbable events like the low entropy state and the fine tuning of the cosmological constant should there then not also be less probable occurrences in out universe?

Things that would be less probable than the entropy state in a multi verse (And still very much absurd) would be things like a perpetual motion machine or a flock of talking seagulls wearing bow ties and drinking wine.

Those things are are more probable than the fine tuning of the universe or the low entropy state. So if multi verses has the capacity to explain that why then are we seeing a host of more probable and absurd things in our universe?

We seem to be living in an ordered and structured universe without the absurd. Which in my mind seems to hint at some sort of intelligence giving it structure and shape... but should it?

(PS To the mods I have asked this question at the philosophy site as well. Seeing as this questions has elements of both physics and philosophy to it I would like an answer from both viewpoints if that is OK)

Comment: The definition of _absurd_ is totally subjective.

Comment: Also you are experiencing heavy observer bias. Lets say (for arguments sake) that 1 in 1 gadZillion (aka 1 in an unreasonably large number of) universes could support life and the probability of a universe containing stars in the shape "I love you" was 1 in 10. What is the chance of the stars having the shape "I love you" in our universe? It's still 1 in 10. All those other universes where its unobserved are irrelevant

Comment: Also this is just a bigger version of "Isn't it amazing that earth is so perfect for life, lucky we evolved here and not on mars"

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the [fine-tuned universe](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Argument_from_design#Argument_from_fine_tuning) argument. Inherently, it is tautological. We developed to the universe. The universe did not develop to us.